# Custom NavigatioItem TitleView when prefersLargeTitles is true

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I would like to set, an attributed string with a words which has different font sizes, to the property title of a navigation item which is a part of a navigation bar with the property prefersLargeTitles set to true.

I have tried to assign a custom view to the property viewTitle of a navigation item but the view is always limited in height to 44 px which is a half of height of the navigation bar with a large title.

Is it possible to add a custom viewTitle which will have the height equal to the height of the navigation bar?

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Page 1",
                                           attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]);

attrString.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: " Chapter 3",
                                            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 19)]));

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
label.attributedText = attrString



let frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 256, height: 88))

let titleView = UIView(frame:CGRect.zero)
titleView.addSubview(label)
label.frame = frame

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
self.navigationItem.titleView?.frame = frame
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you hack the view hierachy, You cannot do it with public api.